# how to auto random increment for post view

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, post-meta

i want edit this code to auto increment not just +2 for each user's click and instead increment number would be random ( + 2 , + 4 , ... )

```php
if( $should_count && ( ( isset( $views_options['use_ajax'] ) && (int) $views_options['use_ajax'] === 0 ) || ( !defined( 'WP_CACHE' ) || !WP_CACHE ) ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $id, 'views', $post_views + 2 );
                do_action( 'postviews_increment_views', $post_views + 2 );
```

---

my full wp postview code bellow:

```
### Function: Calculate Post Views
add_action( 'wp_head', 'process_postviews' );
function process_postviews() {
    global $user_ID, $post;
    if ( is_int( $post ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $post );
    }
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post ) && ! is_preview() ) {
        if ( is_single() || is_page() ) {
            $id = (int) $post->ID;
            $views_options = get_option( 'views_options' );
            if ( !$post_views = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true ) ) {
                $post_views = 0;
            }
            $should_count = false;
            switch( (int) $views_options['count'] ) {
                case 0:
                    $should_count = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if( empty( $_COOKIE[ USER_COOKIE ] ) && (int) $user_ID === 0 ) {
                        $should_count = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if( (int) $user_ID > 0 ) {
                        $should_count = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if ( isset( $views_options['exclude_bots'] ) && (int) $views_options['exclude_bots'] === 1 ) {
                $bots = array(
                    'Google Bot' => 'google'
                    , 'MSN' => 'msnbot'
                    , 'Alex' => 'ia_archiver'
                    , 'Lycos' => 'lycos'
                    , 'Ask Jeeves' => 'jeeves'
                    , 'Altavista' => 'scooter'
                    , 'AllTheWeb' => 'fast-webcrawler'
                    , 'Inktomi' => 'slurp@inktomi'
                    , 'Turnitin.com' => 'turnitinbot'
                    , 'Technorati' => 'technorati'
                    , 'Yahoo' => 'yahoo'
                    , 'Findexa' => 'findexa'
                    , 'NextLinks' => 'findlinks'
                    , 'Gais' => 'gaisbo'
                    , 'WiseNut' => 'zyborg'
                    , 'WhoisSource' => 'surveybot'
                    , 'Bloglines' => 'bloglines'
                    , 'BlogSearch' => 'blogsearch'
                    , 'PubSub' => 'pubsub'
                    , 'Syndic8' => 'syndic8'
                    , 'RadioUserland' => 'userland'
                    , 'Gigabot' => 'gigabot'
                    , 'Become.com' => 'become.com'
                    , 'Baidu' => 'baiduspider'
                    , 'so.com' => '360spider'
                    , 'Sogou' => 'spider'
                    , 'soso.com' => 'sosospider'
                    , 'Yandex' => 'yandex'
                );
                $useragent = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
                foreach ( $bots as $name => $lookfor ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $useragent ) && ( false !== stripos( $useragent, $lookfor ) ) ) {
                        $should_count = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $should_count = apply_filters( 'postviews_should_count', $should_count, $id );
            if( $should_count && ( ( isset( $views_options['use_ajax'] ) && (int) $views_options['use_ajax'] === 0 ) || ( !defined( 'WP_CACHE' ) || !WP_CACHE ) ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $id, 'views', $post_views + 2 );
                do_action( 'postviews_increment_views', $post_views + 2 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just need to [pick a random number](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), save it in a variable so you use the same value twice, and then swap the + 2s for + that variable? Which bit do you need help with?

Comment: And why? Why not +1? That's the actual number of views you've got.

Comment: @Rup yes i want to change codes from constant increment to random increamen. pleas tell me codes i need to replace. tnx

Answer (score 0):

To randomly add 1-5 views, you can change the `if ( $should_count` block at the bottom to:

```php
if( $should_count && ( ( isset( $views_options['use_ajax'] ) && (int) $views_options['use_ajax'] === 0 ) || ( !defined( 'WP_CACHE' ) || !WP_CACHE ) ) ) {
    $random_increment = rand( 1, 5 );
    update_post_meta( $id, 'views', $post_views + $random_increment );
    do_action( 'postviews_increment_views', $post_views + $random_increment );
}
```

I'm still not sure why you'd want to do this though.